# How to select certain rules to implement with StyleCop and .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, stylecop

.net core 1.1 web application and I have added stylecop.analyzers 1.0.0. How can I disable  / deselect certain rules? Currently a lot of references online talk about adding a stylecop.json file or a ruleset but they do not seem to be working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your own custom set of StyleCop Analyzers rules set you should add a ruleset file. `stylecop.json` is more for general settings.

Here is a blog post about setup for .NET Core v1.1: [Visual Studio 2017 StyleCop Analyzers template for .NET Core](https://ignas.me/tech/visual-studio-2017-stylecop-analyzers-template-net-core/).